# What is the difference between AUTO_PASSTHROUGH and PASSTHROUGH?

Tags: istio

I already checked the document of istio.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/#ServerTLSSettings-TLSmode

But I don't understand the difference between AUTO_PASSTHROUGH and PASSTHROUGH perfectly.

Could anyone explain the difference simply?

Comment: Auto = auto detect if it is required or not. Without auto, it is 'forced' to use (as a permanent setting).

Answer (score 3):

Specifying AUTO_PASSTHROUGH doesn't require an additional VirtualService to be configured for the upstream server. The destination will be based on the SNI value.

Specifying PASSTHROUGH does require a VirtualService. The SNI value will be used to match against an appropriate Virtual Service to determine the upstream server.

Hope that clears it up!